# Write a query to display schedule id and date in the format of ‘YYYY-MM-DD’ and name the column as FormattedDate

Tags: oracle

Write a query to display schedule id and date in the format of ‘YYYY-MM-DD’ and name the column `FormattedDate`. Display record in ascending order by schedule id.

```
select schedule_id, to_char(to_date(travel_date,'DD-MON-YY'),'YYYY-MM-DD')
 as FormattedDate from schedule order by schedule_id;
```

This is my code. when I am evaluating this, it is only passing one of the two test cases. My output is as expected but I think there is some error on my code.

**This is the schema:**

[image: Schema]

Comment: Applying a `to_date()` on a column that already is of the type `date` is unnecessary. But your query does what you describe. And nobody can tell why the tests aren't passed without knowing the tests you apply there. Please [edit] the question and include the test criteria if you want help on this.

Comment: Proposed grade: 50 / 100

Result Description
 Failed Test
 Test Case 2

 Summary of tests
+------------------------------+
| 2 tests run / 1 test passed  |
+------------------------------+ this is what i am getting

Comment: You say you're getting the right output, but not passing the test cases. (a) Is this a homework question? (b) What are your test cases?

Comment: A mixed case column alias would need to be quoted (eg "FormattedDate" )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`travel_date` is already a `DATE` data type; there is no need to use `TO_DATE( date_string, format_model )` on it as the function expects a string as the first argument and you are passing a `DATE` so oracle has to apply an implicit conversion (using the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter as the format model) and your statement is effectively:

```
select schedule_id,
       to_char(
         to_date(
           TO_CHAR(
             travel_date,
             (SELECT VALUE FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS WHERE PARAMETER = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT')
           ),
           'DD-MON-YY'
         ),
         'YYYY-MM-DD'
       ) as FormattedDate
from   schedule
order by schedule_id;
```

This will create issues when the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` and `DD-MON-YY` format models are not the same.

Instead, just do:

```
select schedule_id,
       to_char( travel_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD' ) as FormattedDate
from   schedule
order by schedule_id;
```

If the column needs to have the correct case then use a quoted identifier to enforce case-sensitivity:

```
select schedule_id,
       to_char( travel_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD' ) as "FormattedDate"
from   schedule
order by schedule_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select schedule_id,to_char(travel_date,'yyyy-mm-dd')as formatted from schedule order by schedule id asc;
```

It works:)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SCHEDULE_ID, to_char(travel_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd') as Formattedd FROM SCHEDULE ORDER BY SCHEDULE_ID;
```

Works fine